# Passar valores de um UserControl para o Form pai

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Possuo um `Form` principal e 4 `UserControl` com alguns `TextBox`, esses `UserControl` está dentro deste `Form` e minha intenção é pegar os valores dos campos desses `UserControl` a partir de um botão no `Form` principal, por exemplo:

Digito "Teste" em algum campo de um `UserControl` e ao clicar no botão que está no `Form` principal fora do `UserControl`, quero resgatar o valor do campo contido no `UserControl` e atribuir em um `TextBox` no `Form` principal isso é possível?

Comment: SIM é possivel ....

Comment: pode me dar um exemplo por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possivel.

**Forma 1**

---

Na criação do seu [UseControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=net-5.0) adicione um método `GetText()` que retorna o valor (propriedade `Text`) do controle [TextBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=net-5.0) para esse método onde o [Form](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=net-5.0) pode resgatar e utilizar a informação, *exemplo*:

No código do [UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=net-5.0) é criado um `GetText()` que tem o seu retorno do [TextBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=net-5.0) contido no [UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=net-5.0):

```
public partial class UText : UserControl
{
    public string GetText()
    {
        return TxtUText.Text;
    }
    
    public UText()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UText_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

e após adicionar esse [UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=net-5.0) no [Form](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=net-5.0) no [Button](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?view=net-5.0) é só referenciar a variável criada do [UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=net-5.0) e o método `GetText()`:

```
private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = uText1.GetText();
}
```

**Forma 2**

---

A forma 2 consiste em mudar a visibilidade do componente contido no [UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=net-5.0) para `public` porque é sabido que todos os componentes arrastados ou incluidos para dentro [Form](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=net-5.0) tem a sua visibilidade `private` como padrão, mas, selecione o componente e na caixa de propriedades modifique sua visibilidade para `public` como figura explicativa:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no código do botão o componente do [UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=net-5.0) mostra os outros componentes contidos e com essa possibilidade pode também resgatar os seus valores:

```
private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = uText1.TxtUText.Text;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, @novic.